# How can I set up Microsoft BOB on my computer?

Tags: windows-7, installation

I have a 64-bit Windows 7 laptop that I would like to run [Microsoft BOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Bob) on.

How can I obtain a copy of Microsoft BOB and how could I set it up?

Comment: ... just don't ...

Comment: @Nick You have something against BOB?

Comment: Sounds like someone left their PC unlocked and a "friend" is playing a practical joke...

Comment: Have you tried running it under Virtual XP mode?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a post about [running Bob on Virtual PC 2004](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/microsoft-bob-lives), back in -- well -- 2004, probably on XP. Bob runs on top of Windows 3.11 and Windows 95.

With Windows 7, you can try the current VPC, Windows Virtual PC. Install 3.11 or 95 in a VM, and then install Bob on that. Note that Windows VPC probably does not have the integration  features for older versions of Windows. Sometimes installing the ones from VPC 2007 or VPC 2004 works.

Answer (score 2):

If im not mistaken, MS BOB is a 16 bit application and simply will not work on Windows 7.

Comment: windows 7 *64* bit. Its a 16 bit application

Answer (score 2):

I can say for a fact that Microsoft BOB DOES work on 32 bit windows and were you able to get a copy (which is possible), it most likely would run on a modern system - I've run it on windows XP, and will give it a spin and update it on windows 7. Unfortunately (or fortunately) its abandonware and not really legal to download (and the site i think i got it from, winhistory.de took down its link to bob), so i cannot help you with finding a copy(but googling helps).

64 bit windows lacks 16 bit support, so you're out of luck outside an emulator.

Comment: I also looked for copies of the program, but it's either been removed or has no one hosting it anymore.

Comment: Sadly you cant get bob from MSDN or TechNet...

Answer (score -1):

MS Bob will not work on Windows 7 32 bit or 64 bit, it can't find utopia.dll and has trouble locating home.exe even though both files are clearly there in the correct directories.  I have tried it on Windows XP in the past and that has worked.